# Difference in the C codes?

Tags: c, function, while-loop, infinite-loop, decrement

Code 1 :-

```
int f(int val) {
    int x=0;
    while(val > 0) {
        x = x + f(val--);
    }
    return val;
}
```

---

Code 2:-

```
int g(int val) {
    int x = 0;
    while(val > 0) {
        x= x + g(val-1);
    }
    return val;
}
```

---

What is the difference in the execution of the codes `f(3)` and `g(3)` ?

---

The `Code 1` is quite clear to me. Then `f(3)` will keep calling itself, getting deeper and deeper, and when the space used to keep track of recursive function, it is filled up, and we get the stack overflow error.

But, I am actually stuck in the execution of the **2nd code**. I ran it and got infinite loop.

Also, I have read that `val--` can be written as `val-1`. So, How am I going wrong in interpreting the line `val-1`, as both of them are behaving quite different .

Comment: You got an infinite loop because the value of `val` never changes in `g`. Something you would have noticed had you debugged it at all.

Comment: This is a good example where paper debugging can be helpful. At each step in execution, write the value of all variables and decide what the code says happens next.

Comment: `val--` and `val - 1` are two very different things. The first one changes the value of `val`, but the second does not.

Comment: The effect of `val--` on `val` itself is the same as `val = val - 1`, note the assignment.

Comment: The first changes `val` in each loop iteration.   The second doesn't, so (if `val` is positive) will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: closing a question if you problem is solved is always a good idea :)

Comment: Let's say `val` has a value of `42`. Given that, `val--` has a value of `42` and `val - 1` has a value of `41`. Furthermore, the 1st expression has a side effect of decreasing `val` making its value be `41` at the next sequence point.

Answer (score 1):

`val--` is equivalent to `val = val -1` so it decreases the value of `val` by 1 and stores the new value as well (decrementing). While `val -1` just decreases and returns the new value without storing it in the variable `val` (no actual decrementing hapenning). This is why you have an infinite loop. I recommend these changes:

```
int g(int val) {
    int x = 0;
    while(val > 0) {
        val = val - 1;
        x= x + g(val);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Here is a reference on decrement and increment operators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Answer (score 0):

val-- decreases val by 1 and saves it back into val, while val - 1 simply subtracts 1 from val which means you will never escape your while loop.